# JQuery - Using selector within $(this) Object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to filter information that I am pulling.

I start by pulling all elements of a table using a selector

```
var ptable = $("table[class*='Display'] > tbody > tr");
```

Outputs as such (`console.log`):

```
Object {
    0: <tr>,
    1: <tr>,
    2: <tr>,
    3: <tr>,
    4: <tr>,
    5: <tr>,
    6: <tr>,
    7: <tr>,
    8: <tr>,
    9: <tr>,
    397 more…
}
```

Then I want to filter for each piece of the array,
 `ptable.each(function(){...})`

I am looking for :

```
$(this).$("a[class*='productnamecolor']");
```

However this portion of the code is crashing or invalid?
My console logs stop at this point.

What am I doing wrong?

Trying to use an `If` statement in conjunction to only take out relevant information as the script traverses through the web page.

Comment: It's ***well worth your time*** to read through [the jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com) beginning to end. It only takes an hour, two tops, and it repays you that time immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(this).filter("a[class*='productnamecolor']");
$(this).find("a[class*='productnamecolor']");
```

The first filters on the current results, the second finds nested matches on the previous results.

Comment: Thank You. I ended up using the filter.

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).find("a[class*='productnamecolor']");`

You can use the function `.find()` which will try to locate the `a[class*='productnamecolor']` inside the `this` context

Answer (score 0):

If those anchors are child elements of the table. You can use `.find()`

```
$(this).find("a[class*='productnamecolor']");
```